# Setting test values for $route.current.params in AngularJS unit tests

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the O'Reilly AngularJS book to learn AngularJS. In the book then create a service which has the job of loading a $resource like so:

```
services.factory('Recipe', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/recipes/:id', {id: '@id'});
}]);

services.factory('RecipeLoader', ['Recipe', '$route', '$q', function(Recipe, $route, $q) {
  return function() {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    Recipe.get({id: $route.current.params.recipeId}, function(recipe) {
      delay.resolve(recipe);
    }, function() {
      delay.reject('Unable to fetch recipe '  + $route.current.params.recipeId);
    });
    return delay.promise;
  };
});
```

However in the book the neglect to test this service and I'm trying to work out how to do it. I've created a test which uses the mock *$httpBackend* but the problem I'm having is when the tests are run $route.current is undefined.

I've tried injecting $route into my test and setting $route.current.params.id = 1; but that doesn't seem to work. Has anyone got any suggestions on how to set a test value in $route.current.params?

Many thanks!!!

### SOLUTION

I've found a better solution, I've made the factory take an id as the parameter like so:

```
services.factory('RecipeLoader', ['Recipe', '$route', '$q', function(Recipe, $route, $q) {
  return function(recipeId) {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    Recipe.get({id: recipeId}, function(recipe) {
      delay.resolve(recipe);
    }, function() {
      delay.reject('Unable to fetch recipe '  + $route.current.params.recipeId);
    });
    return delay.promise;
  };
});
```

Then modified the resolve parameter in the $routeProvider to pass in the ID. Like so

```
.when('/recipe/view/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'views/recipe/view.html',
  controller: 'RecipeViewCtrl',
  resolve: {
    renewal: function (RecipeLoader, $route) {
      return RecipeLoader($route.current.params.id);
    }
  }
})
```

This feels like better design to me anyway as the controller is more specific about what inputs it requires.

Comment: You would have to mock the `$route` object. It only gets loaded with values when doing something like an end-to-end test or when running the site in a full browser.  So in order to test it, you'll need to supply a mock for it

Comment: Thanks, I had suspected that but I'm not really sure how to mock $route yet (early days).Anyway I've actually worked out a neater solution. See original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the solution you have stumbled upon is the better way of creating this service, and testing it. For the service, it should be independent of magic, like the route or state, and should be passed in what it needs.

The code in the book was more to show how to use Services and Resolves together, rather than proper way of writing services.

With services, whenever possible, prefer to pass in parameters rather than reading them from magic state.

That said, it is an interesting question in that, how do you mock certain services when you need to test other services which depend on them.

There are two ways you can override services in your tests:

1. Override it for the purpose of a single unit test or describe block. After initializing your own module using `beforeEach(module('myModule'))`, you can create a module inline as follows:

   ```
   beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
      $provide.factory('ServiceToOverride', function() {
          // Return overriden service here
      });
   }));
   ```

   Link for this: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0vQ71ySe0EWmijO7S28?p=preview)
2. Create a module for general purpose mocking, say `angular.module('myApp.mock')`, and define your overriden service inside of that. Then, after your beforeEach to load the module in your tests, also load this module using `beforeEach(module('myApp.mock'));`

The latter is more useful for more intensive and logic encapsulating mocks, while the former is great for quick, throwaway, single use mocks.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. Very helpful!